# Random functions in numpy.random

Tags: python, numpy

Why does `numpy.random` provide `rand`, `random`, `random_sample`, `sample`, `ranf`, which all look the same from the documentation? They all make uniform random array of any shape in `[0.0, 1.0)`.

Comment: Some are described as `convenience` functions, others listed as `compatibility`.  The current `numpy` was created around 2005 by merging several numeric packages, so some overlapping functions were kept for backward compatibility.

Comment: That is precisely correct.

Comment: @hpaulj, you should post an answer... it's a good question.